# Донастройка datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Есть календарь *datepicker*, в котором отмечены некоторые даты. Данные приходят с сервера и меняют цвет фона конкретного числа через свойство `beforeShowDay`.

Под календарем - таблица с более подробной информацией о датах.

Задача:

1. При наведении мыши на дату (в календаре), подсветить (цвет текста, жирность) все даты из группы (в группе может быть одна или несколько дат (все они имеют одинаковый класс).
2. Подсветить строку в таблице, которая описывает эту группу. И наоборот при наведении мыши на строку в таблице - подсвечивать соответствующие даты в календаре.

Мысли/вопросы:

1. Технически к каждой ячейке задаем класс, который будет флагом того, что ячейка относится к тем, которые надо подсвечивать и второй класс с номером группы (это мне не очень нравится).
2. Добавляем обработку события MouseOver и MouseOut для класса-флага. В документации datepicker этого найти не смог.

Если кто может, что рассказать по этому вопросу (или хотя бы направить в нужном направлении) - буду очень признателен.

Спасибо.

```
$(function() {
$.datepicker.regional['ru'] = {
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
 };
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ru']);
$( '.datepicker' ).datepicker({ altField: "#show",
                            altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                            numberOfMonths: [ 1, 3 ],
                            stepMonths: 3,
                            beforeShowDay: fBeforeShowDay,
                            onSelect : function(value,b) {
                                              var AppartID = $(this).attr('appart-id');
                                              var d = value.split('.');
                                              var DateTS = (new Date(d[2],d[1]-1,d[0])).getTime();

                                              var ok = $.inArray(DateTS, SelectedDays[AppartID]);
                                              if (ok == -1) SelectedDays[AppartID].push(DateTS)
                                              else { SelectedDays[AppartID].splice(ok,1) };

                                              SelectedDays[AppartID].sort(function(a, b) {
                                                  return a - b;
                                              });

                                       }
                         }) //.datepicker

function fBeforeShowDay(date) {
   var AppartID = $(this).attr('appart-id');
   if (typeof DayStatus[AppartID] === 'undefined') // Нет ни одного дня в БД!
    { return[false, "poly1c0 poly2c0", SelectableDayStatus[0].Name]; }
   else
    {
   var cds = date.toLocaleString().slice(0, 10);
   var CurrentDayStyleFlag = (typeof DayStatus[AppartID][cds] === 'undefined')?0:DayStatus[AppartID][cds]['Status'];
   var CurrentDaySelectable = SelectableDayStatus[CurrentDayStyleFlag].Selectable;

   var pdate = new Date(date.getTime()-86400000);
   var pds = pdate.toLocaleString().slice(0, 10);
   var PrevDayStyleFlag = (typeof DayStatus[AppartID][pds] === 'undefined')?0:DayStatus[AppartID][pds]['Status'];

   for (var i=0; i<SelectedDays[AppartID].length; i++) {
      if (date.getTime() == SelectedDays[AppartID][i])
       { CurrentDayStyleFlag = 2; }
      if (pdate.getTime() == SelectedDays[AppartID][i])
       { PrevDayStyleFlag = 2; }
   };

   if (CurrentDayStyleFlag > 2)
    {
       var ReservID = DayStatus[AppartID][cds]['ReservID'];
       var isItemPresent = $("#ReservListItem"+ReservID).index();
       if (isItemPresent == -1)
        {
          console.log (cds, DayStatus[AppartID][cds]['ReservID'], isItemPresent);
          $('<tr id="ReservListItem'+DayStatus[AppartID][cds]['ReservID']+'">'+
            '<td>'+DayStatus['RESERV'][ReservID]['DateReservedBegin']+' - '
                  +DayStatus['RESERV'][ReservID]['DateReservedEnd']+' ('
                  +DayStatus['RESERV'][ReservID]['ReservedDays']+')</td>'+
            '<td>'+DayStatus['RESERV'][ReservID]['UserFullName']+'<br>'
                  +DayStatus['RESERV'][ReservID]['Phone']+'</td>'+
            '<td>t3</td>'+
           '</tr>').appendTo($("#ReservList"+AppartID));
        }
    }

   return[CurrentDaySelectable, "poly1c"+PrevDayStyleFlag+" poly2c"+CurrentDayStyleFlag, SelectableDayStatus[CurrentDayStyleFlag].Name]
 }
}; //function fBeforeShowDay(date)
```

Comment: что за datepicker используется? стоит добавить код который уже есть

Comment: А какие они бывают? Последняя версия jquery-ui. Код, конечно, есть. Но он очень громоздкий и по сути не влияет на суть вопроса. Сейчас попробую выложить.

Comment: _А какие они бывают?_ - есть куча плагинов для jQuery с календарями, плюс например какой-нибудь бутстрап

Comment: не надо приводить **весь** код. нужно добавить _минимальный_ пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

События, которые позволяют решить данную задачу:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter",'[data-handler="selectDay"]',function(){
  var date = new Date($(this).data("year"), $(this).data("month"),$(this).text())
  console.log(date)
})

$(document).on("mouseleave",'[data-handler="selectDay"]',function(){});
```